# Modify SELECT Query Display Output

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is it possible to modify the data displayed from a `SELECT` statement?

*example:*

```
SELECT username, gender, age 
FROM t   
WHERE username LIKE '%tom%';
```

output: `c:/tom`|`m`|`20`

desired output: `tom`|`m`|`20`

Comment: Yes; but what is the logic/pattern behind the modification required ? Please add those details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you might really want:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(username, '/', -1) as name, gender, age 
FROM t   
WHERE username LIKE '%/tom%';
```

This is more generalized.  It will select anything after the last slash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUBSTRING function:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(username,3) as username, gender, age 
FROM t  
WHERE username LIKE '%tom%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `right()` function

```
SELECT right(username,3), gender, age 
FROM t   
WHERE username LIKE '%tom%';
```